# Introduction to the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory

I think I did well here, but need to hear your opinion. Is this right?
The problem says: For all $n\in \Bbb N$, if $4^n-1$ is prime, then $n$ is odd.
And i got this, by contradiction:
Let's say $4^n-1$ is not prime and $n$ is even, then $n=2k$ for any $k \in \Bbb Z$,
so $4^{2k}-1=(4^{k})^2-1=(2^{2k}-1)(2^{2k}+1)$ and we can see that neither of these factors are even numbers, where there's at least one $n$ where $4^n-1$ is a composite number and contradicts our original statement.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need feedback regarding my solution

Comment: $4^n-1$ is always divisible by $3$ , hence $4^n-1$ is only prime for $n=1$ , which is odd.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your proof clearly, otherwise it won't be even possible to tell if it is correct. You may have right thoughts and I am not sure if the problem is with writing or with thinking. I will "dissect" what you are saying and show what needs to be clarified.

> Let's say $4^n-1$ is not prime...

This sounds like you are *assuming* $4^n-1$ is not prime. If that is what you want, this is unnecessary. The problem is not asking you about anything in the case $4^n-1$ is not prime. It is asking about $n$ in case $4^n-1$ *is* prime.

> ... and $n$ is even,

So indeed we should try to assume that $4^n-1$ *is* prime and $n$ is even and derive the contradiction. The negation of "If X then Y" is "X is true but Y is false".

> ... then $n=2k$ for any $k \in \Bbb Z$,

Sort of correct, but I would not say "any". I would say "some". "Any" means "for every", i.e. you are saying $n=2k$ for all $k\in\mathbb Z$ which is obviously false. You really want to say "there exists $k$ such that $n=2k$".

> so $4^{2k}-1=(4^{k})^2-1=(2^{2k}-1)(2^{2k}+1)$

Correct

> ... and we can see that neither of these factors are even numbers,

What does that matter?

> ... where there's at least one $n$ where $4^n-1$ is a composite number...

Why "there's at least one"? You want a stronger statement: for *any* even $n$, $4^n-1$ is composite. And that is true as $4^n-1=(4^k-1)(4^k+1)$ as you noticed - effectively showing that $4^n-1$ can be broken up as a product of two numbers. *That* is the fact worth mentioning in the proof.

In addition, both of those numbers have to be different than $1$, which you did not show.

> ... and contradicts our original statement.

At this point I am confused what you have assumed, what you have claimed to have proven and what you have actually proven. Certainly "there's at least one $n$ where $4^n-1$ is a composite number" is not contradicting "if $4^n−1$ is prime, then $n$ is odd" anymore than, say, "at least one mammal is not a monkey" does not contradict the statement "Every monkey is a furry mammal".

---

So, the bottom line is - identify if those are defects in your *writing* or in your *thinking* (i.e. logic). If the former, fix your style. Don't add irrelevant details. Follow your logic in your writing exactly, precisely stating what you claim and what implies what (and why). If it is in your *logic*, then fix that. Think in terms of logical rules applied to everyday objects (furry mammals etc.) and check if your thinking is right before trying to write it down.

Answer (score 0):

Statement: If $4^n-1$ is prime, then $n$ is odd.

Contrapositive: $4^n-1$ is not prime (composite), if $n$ is even.

Therefore, what you have proved is the contrapositive of the statement that you wanted to prove. Your proof is completely fine.

But since you mention that you are proving this by means of a contradiction argument, there are flaws in your logic.

> Let's say $4^n−1$ is not prime and $n$ is even, then $n=2k$ for any $k\in \mathbb Z$

You would assume that the claim is false: There exists an even $n$ such that $4^n-1$ is prime.( **Not $n=2k$ for any $k\in \mathbb Z$ but for a single $k \in \mathbb Z$**.)